# Same mask results different total pixels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extract-by-mask

I'm cutting two layers with extract by mask tool but they lead different total pixels. For example when I did it for WorldClim's layers it results total 300.000 pixels but when I did it for NASA's fire data it results 230.000 pixels. Any idea for why this is happening? I used excatly the same shaplefile while doing it.

Comment: This is most likely due to varying pixel size.

Comment: Try to find resolution of each raster layer. You could find it in layer properties.

Comment: okay I already looked it but I don't think it was the reason but appareantly it is. Thanks for the help.